# Fetching unique rows from one table that columns reference has not in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've two table first Name `orders`
2nd named `printing`
`orders` table structure like this

`id   job_code  job_name    qty`
`1      597      xyz       1000`
`2      598     lmn        2500`
`3      599     oqr        20000`
`4      600     odc        15000`

and `printing` table structure like this

`id job_code    dispatch    qty`
`1    598       yes         1800`
`2    600       yes         1456`

i want to select all `job.code` From `orders` which is not in `printing` table

I tried myself with this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.job_code, orders.job_name, orders.qty FROM orders  
INNER JOIN printing
ON orders.job_code <> printing.job_code ORDER BY orders.job_code DESC LIMIT 10;
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.job_code, orders.job_name, orders.qty FROM orders  
INNER JOIN printing
ON orders.job_code NOT IN (printing.job_code) ORDER BY orders.job_code DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

but it'll return all jobs which held on `orders` and `printing` tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT orders.job_code, orders.job_name, orders.qty 
FROM
    orders 
WHERE
    orders.job_code
    NOT IN
        (SELECT printing.job_code FROM printing)
ORDER BY
    orders.job_code DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It works for me thanks Blank Head..
can you please tell one more query??
how to select job_code from orders even same code include in printing table but printing.qty is less then orders.qty

Comment: SELECT job_code FROM orders LEFT JOIN printing USING job_code WHERE printing.qty < orders.qty

Answer (score 1):

```
select job_code from orders 
where job_cobe not in (select job_code from printing)
```

Comment: It works for me thanks Mikhail Timofeev..
can you please tell one more query??
how to select job_code from orders even same code include in printing table but printing.qty is less then orders.qty

Answer (score 0):

use the query like this

```
SELECT job_code FROM `orders` left join printingorders on orders.job_code not in ( select job_code from printingorders)
```

This will give you the result. I tried in my Phpmyadmin.